# Can you blow bubbles on top of Mount Everest?

Tags: pressure, temperature, bubbles

Can you blow bubbles on top of Mount Everest? How would they be different in low temperatures and pressures?

Comment: The soap solution that you are using would very likely be frozen solid.  If it wasn't, I would expect the soap film that you were blowing on to quickly freeze before you could blow it into a bubble.

Comment: That brings up an interesting question, is there some other solution that exists in a liquid form at those temperatures and can be used for blowing bubbles? Can't we make bubbles out of other liquids beyond soapy water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force due to pressure over a given area is $F=AP$. A bubble will have three forces to consider. 1. Air pressure from air inside the bubble pushing the wall of the bubble outward (trying to make the bubble bigger) 2. Air pressure from air outside the bubble pushing the wall of the bubble inward (trying to make the bubble smaller), and 3. a surface tension of the bubble itself (which will try to make the bubble smaller).

Ignoring surface tension for the moment, if you can create a bubble at sea level, and bring it up to higher elevations where the air pressure is lower, the bubble should expand because the air pressure inside will (initially) be larger than the surrounding air pressure outside. This will tend to make the bubble expand until the two forces cancel each other (air pressure pushing in and air pressure pushing out). Taking surface tension into account, if we assume that surface tension does not change, the above answer should suffice. If surface tension does change which is reasonable to expect (due to different outside pressures, temperatures, and bubble wall thickness) this would probably depend on what the bubble is made of and how that (soap film, fluid, whatever) changes with the environment.

The equation for force above does not include temperature. I may say that temperature is implicitly included in that pressure depends on temperature depending on how you describe your gas (ideal gas, Van der Waals gas, etc).